# SSL to SSL Redirects in IIS - Possible?

Tags: iis, ssl, redirect

We have a situation where we would like to redirect https://service1.domain.com to https://service2.domain.com.  I know this is very simple with http endpoints, but I'm not too sure about https.

We have some legacy windows application web service clients that will not be updating their software version soon, and we cannot update their web references to https://service2.domain.com.

Is there any way to leave these web service clients pointing to https://service1.domain.com, but have their requests forwarded to (and responded to by) https://service2.comain.com?

The old server is running IIS 6.0.  The new server is running IIS 7.0.  We could probably upgrade it to 7.5 if needed, but I'm not certain.

We could also probably make a seamless transition of the old web service to a new server using public DNS, but we cannot change the DNS name of "service1.domain.com."

Thanks ServerFault!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the servers at both endpoints are responding with a valid certificate for their name (old server's certificate should be `service1.domain.com`, new server's should be `service2.domain.com`, matching the DNS name that the client's accessing for each), then a 30x redirect from the old SSL'd site to the new one is no problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the most efficient approach, but you can set up a reverse proxy in IIS 7 -- in this case requests to service1.domain.com would be forwarded by IIS to service2.domain.com and replied to, but to the clients it would seem like pure traffic to service1.domain.com -- http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/